# AngularJS directive for <input type="file"> validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to make a directive able to handle an `<input type="file">` validation inside a `<form>` given that AngularJS doesn't have support for this...It kind of works to check if a file is selected, but I also have a `<textarea>` in the form so when I select a file the form gets state $valid=true, but just by typing into the `<textarea>` makes the form become $valid=false even though I haven't set a validation for the `<textarea>`. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?. Here is a simplified example to illustrate the problem:

---

My app.js file:

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});



app.directive('validFile', function () {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: '^form',

      link: function (scope,elem,attrs, ctrl) {

        elem.bind("change", function(e) {
          console.log("change");
          scope.$apply(function(){
              ctrl.$valid=true;
              ctrl.$invalid=false;
          });
        });

      }
    };
  });
```

My index.html file:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-form="myForm" >
    <input ng-model="filename" valid-file required type="file"/>
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>&nbsp;Ok</button>
    <div >
      <textarea name="observations" rows="3" cols="50" ng-model="observations"></textarea>
    </div> 
    <p> 
      Input is valid: {{myForm.$valid}} Input is invalid: {{myForm.$invalid}}
      <br>Selected file: {{filename}}
      <br>Area is valid: {{myForm.observations.$valid}} Area is invalid: {{myForm.observations.$invalid}}
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

there's a working plnkr of what I just said: 
    http://plnkr.co/edit/k3KZpdX5q3pelWN21NVp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack would be to just take the text-area out of the ng-form like this -

```
<div ng-form="myForm">
  <input id="userUpload" ng-model="filename" archivo-valido 
         name="userUpload" required type="file"
         accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
</div>
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>&nbsp;Ok
</button>
```

Problem is the `Form` is `invalid` in the beginning but you just force the value to `true` on `change`. Once you write something in the `textarea`, the `Form` reverts back to its original `false` value. I don't understand the code in your directive -

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
>  scope.$apply(function(){
>         if(true){ // will always evaluate to true. Why the else part then?
>           ctrl.$valid=true;
>           ctrl.$invalid=false;
>         }else{
>           ctrl.$valid=false;
>         }
>       });
> ```

A better approach would be to write [Custom Validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) on each of your ngModels like this -

```
app.directive('archivoValido', function() {
return {
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
  ctrl.$validators.archivoValido = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
      // consider empty models to be valid
      return true;
    }
     // your custom validation here
     ...
     // it is invalid
    return false;
  };
 }
};
});
```

Comment: Hi, I just modified code so the piece of code you said you "don't understand" it's clearer(it is meant to make the input always valid so we can see how the textarea it's what makes the program fail) also I changed the html code so I can see `form.textArea.$valid` and `form.textArea.$invalid` but doesn't show as you said, textArea is always $valid=true and $invalid=false.

Comment: @gerard Thanks for making the answer clearer. Regarding your doubt, it's not the `form.textArea.$valid` that changes, but `form.$valid` that reverts back to its original `false` value when the `textArea` is changed.